# Unit Testing: Karma-Jasmine not resolving Promise without implicitly calling $rootScope.$digest();

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an `Angular` service that makes a call to the server and fetch the user list. The service returns a `Promise`.

**Problem**

Promise is not being resolved until and unless I call `$rootScope.$digest();` either in the service or in the test itself.

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        rootScope.$digest();
    }, 5000);
```

Apparently, Calling `$rootScope.$digest();` is a workaround and I cannot call it in the angular service so I am calling it in the `unit test` with an interval of 5 seconds which I think is a bad practice.

**Request**

Please suggest an actual solution for this.

Given below is the test that I have written.

```
   // Before each test set our injected Users factory (_Users_) to our local Users variable
    beforeEach(inject(function (_Users_, $rootScope) {
        Users = _Users_;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    }));

    /// test getUserAsync function
    describe('getting user list async', function () {

        // A simple test to verify the method getUserAsync exists
        it('should exist', function () {
            expect(Users.getUserAsync).toBeDefined();
        });


        // A test to verify that calling getUserAsync() returns the array of users we hard-coded above
        it('should return a list of users async', function (done) {
            Users.getUserAsync().then(function (data) {
                expect(data).toEqual(userList);
                done();
            }, function (error) {
                expect(error).toEqual(null);
                console.log(error.statusText);
                done();
            });

            ///WORK AROUND
            setTimeout(function () {
                rootScope.$digest();
            }, 5000);
        });
    })
```

**service**

```
  Users.getUserAsync = function () {
    var defered = $q.defer();

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseUrl + '/users'
    }).then(function (response) {
      defered.resolve(response);
    }, function (response) {
      defered.reject(response);
    });

    return defered.promise;
  }
```

Comment: `$http` returns a promise on its own. Theres ways of mocking it and controlling it in your test. i'd advise looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can cause the promises to flush with a call to `$timeout.flush()`. It makes your tests a little bit more synchronous.

Here's an example:

```
   it('should return a list of users async', function (done) {
        Users.getUserAsync().then(function (data) {
            expect(data).toEqual(userList);
            done();
        }, function (error) {
            expect(error).toEqual(null);
            console.log(error.statusText);
            done();
        });

        $timeout.flush();
    });
```

Aside: the failback won't be handled so it adds additional complexity to the test.

Comment: Pardon, but can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: @VikasBansal what would you like to know?

Comment: On every API call, I am calling `setTimeout`. I have more than 12 APIes to test. So it';s a bit annoying to wait. most of the API are taking 2 seconds to emit a response, so I can reduce the time to 2sec instead of 5sec but still.... is it the only way?

Comment: this is what I got : `1) should return a list of users async
     Users factory getting user list async
     Error: No deferred tasks to be flushed`

Comment: @VikasBansal please share your implementation of `getUserAsync`.